# How to use OsConstants in a switch statement

Tags: android, switch-statement, constants, errno

I have this code:

```
ErrnoException errno = (ErrnoException)lastException.getCause();
switch (errno.errno) {
    case OsConstants.EHOSTUNREACH:

        break;
}
```

but Android Studio gives me the error:

> Error:(339, 21) error: constant expression required

but, `OsConstants.EHOSTUNREACH` is constant (from OsConstants.class):

```
public static final int EHOSTUNREACH = 0;
```

**Update** I downloaded the `OsConstants` java file and it gives me this (still I would assume something in `OsConstants` to be, well, constant):

```
public static final int EHOSTUNREACH = placeholder();
```

Comment: From what is posted here, this should work. It may be the tools acting up. Have you tried cleaning and rebuilding, re-syncing gradle, or even invalidating caches and restarting android studio?

Comment: @Stephen my point exactly. I restarted Android Studio, but that didn't work.